# How to store current date and time in Sqlite using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, sqlite

How to store current date and time in Sqlite using PhoneGap?

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myorder(orderid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,cdatetime VARCHAR)");

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO myorder(orderid,cdatetime) VALUES(NULL,"01/01/2012 01:00:00")',[],successOrderfunction,errorfunction);
```

Is it correct way to store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the current datetime as long.
Define your table column with the long-datatype and insert your value like this:

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myorder(orderid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cdatetime  long)");

tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO myorder(cdatetime) VALUES("+myDate.getTime()+")",[],successOrderfunction,errorfunction);
```

By the way. There is no need to use autoincrement. If you try to insert a null value in a primary key integer the field is automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the largest value of that column.

Comment: If i use long datatype,can i query the table order by cdatetime?

Comment: yes you can. A higher date has a higher long value. "Between" operations are possible too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use sqlite or phonegap but you cannot add null in your pk table.
Add a number or don't add anything at all.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO myorder(cdatetime) VALUES("01/01/2012 01:00:00")',[],successOrderfunction,errorfunction);
```

This should work, you created an incremental pk.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO myorder(orderid,cdatetime) VALUES(1, "01/01/2012 01:00:00")',[],successOrderfunction,errorfunction);
```

This should also work, I think in sqlite you can add pk manually.

Comment: most RMDB systems mysql, mssql and sqlite allow you to pass a NULL for the Autoincrement Primary Key and the DB will generate the next autoinc number for you which is what he is doing here.

Comment: Maybe for sqlite it does, like I said I don't use it. But I don't think mysql and mssql will allow you to null your way into the pk. I remember null-related errors and code-ethical errors when I too thought you could.

Comment: Both mysql and mssql allow this syntax `Insert into mytable(MyID, title) Values (Null, 'My Value')`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expens (Etype TEXT,amount REAL,created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');`